# Dynamically Name Output File Using Azure Data Flow Cache Sink Values

Tags: azure, caching, azure-data-factory

I have set up an azure data flow cache sink to get the Min and Max work dates from my input file.

I created an aggregate branch in the data flow that gets the min({Work Date}) and max({Work Date}). I then created sink with the Sink Type set to Cache that has just the MinWorkDate and MaxWorkDate columns. When I do a data preview I see the expected results (2021-03-08 and 2021-03-14). They are cast as strings.

I need to reuse those values to dynamically name my final output file. When I attempt to use them in my output file name I get an unresolved syntax error.

The syntax I am using is for the data flow output Sink Setting File name:
concat("ProcessedRange_", cachedMinMaxDates#outputs()[1].MinWorkDate, "*to*", cachedMinMaxWorkDates#outputs()[1].MaxDate, "_Result.txt")

I have tried casting them as dates and then use toString in my concat statement. I get the same unresolved syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this on my side. It seems that Cached expression doesn't support to be used to set file name, although you won't get error from expression builder.

My test:

1. use Cached expression in `DerivedColumn` transformation and it can work.
   [image]

[image]

2. when I use Cached expression to set file name, I got the following error.

[image]

[image]

As a workaround, you can use Lookup activity and get maxDate,minDate in pipeline. Then concat them as filename and pass to your data flow.